# Grep, find, awk

Tags: bash, awk

How can I grep, find and awk for listing directory name and specific file extension in that directory in Linux terminal, then formatting to table directory name and file name into two separate columns.

```
find /tmp/Directory* type f -name "*xls" -ls

17    0 -rw-------   1             /tmp/Directory1/file1.xls
19    0 -rw-------   1             /tmp/Directory2/file2.xls
20    0 -rw-------   1             /tmp/Directory3/file3.xls
```

Example:

```
/tmp/Directory1/file1.xls;
/tmp/Directory2/file2.xls;
/tmp/Directory3/file3.xls;
```

I need to format this and output to csv file like a table with column of :

**Dirname    filename**

```
Directory1 file1.xls
Directory2 file2.xls
Directory3 file3.xls
```

Thanks,

Comment: Use [edit] to clarify the format and the explanation of the question. Currently it is unclear what you want to do.

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Why do you `find ... ls` if you just want the name of the file?

Answer (score 3):

```
find /tmp/Directory* type f -name "*.xls" |
awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1), $NF}'

find /tmp/Directory* type f -name "*.xls" |
sed -r 's:.*([^/]+)/([^/]+)$:\1 \2:'
```